# Pythonic way of handling typing Optional?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I'm parsing dict coming from elsewhere and the value is optional

`a: typing.Optional = elsewhere_dict.get(a)`

When I want to run any 3d party functions on it, I call
`b = foo(a) if a is not None else None`
 and I cant pass `None` to `foo` or wrap `foo`.
Is there a better way to call this, without repeating `if a is not None else None`?
Smth like `b = call_optional(a, foo)` but built-in or from std lib?

Comment: Slightly shorter is `b = None if a is None else foo(a)` (though it probably deemphasizes the call to `foo` more than you might like). There's nothing built-in, but a lifting operator like `lambda f: lambda x: None if x is None else f(x)` is trivial enough to define; you can then use it (let's say you named it `fmap`) as `fmap(foo)(elsewhere_dict.get(a))`.

Comment: What's the reason why you aren't allowed to wrap `foo`?

Comment: I can wrap it, but It's not the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything built-in for that, but it is rather trivial to implement `call_optional` yourself:

```
def call_optional(arg, func):
    if arg is not None:
        return func(arg)
```